# How to fix Jquery modal popup in Safari Browser?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, popup, javascript-framework

I getting problem in PopUp position in safari. I used "**jquery.jmodal.js**" for Confirmation box in my web application It work good in all browsers except safari browser.

check image what I exactly getting issue..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at [jmodal](http://code.google.com/p/jmodal/)'s code.  In my opinion, it is a very poorly-done plugin.  It also hasn't been updated in a couple years.

I'd *highly* recommend switching to [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com)'s [dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).